# Gson deserializing with changing field types

Tags: java, json, gson

i have an API-Call that returns:

```
{
  "id": 550,
  "favorite": false,
  "rated": {
    "value": 7.5
  },
  "watchlist": false
}
```

or

```
{
  "id": 550,
  "favorite": false,
  "rated": false,
  "watchlist": false
}
```

so the "rated"-Field is sometimes an object or an boolean.
How do i deserialize something like that with Gson?

my Object so far looks like:

```
public class Status{
    @Expose public boolean favorite;
    @Expose public Number id;
    @Expose public Rated rated;
    @Expose public boolean watchlist;
}
public class Rated{
    @Expose public Number value;
}
```

Comment: What value would you like the resulting `rated` field to have in either case?

Comment: `null` or filled with the object

Comment: What is the point of having to diferent type of Objects in the same code? I think your problem is that false means "null"... so rated should even disapear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for this to work, one way is to implement `TypeAdapter<Rated>` - something like this:

```
public class RatedAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Rated> {

    public Rated read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        reader.beginObject();
        reader.nextName();

        Rated rated;
        try {
            rated = new Rated(reader.nextDouble());
        } catch (IllegalStateException jse) {
            // We have to consume JSON document fully.
            reader.nextBoolean();
            rated = null;
        }

        reader.endObject();

        return rated;
    }

    public void write(JsonWriter writer, Rated rated) throws IOException {
        if (rated == null) {
            writer.value("false");
        } else {
            writer.value(rated.value);
        }
    }
}
```

When you have `TypeAdapter` in place, all you have to do is to register it with `GsonBuilder` and create new `Gson` like this:

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Rated.class, new RatedAdapter());
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    //Let's try it
    Status status = gson.fromJson(json, Status.class);
```

With this type adapter installed, Gson will try to convert all properties named `rated` to appropriate `Rated` Java object.